# Installing/Booting

Tags: boot, mac

I have a working desktop running windows 7.

I also have an old MacBook that has a completely empty hardrive (no OS, no nothing).

I have been told that I can make a bootable USB drive using ubuntu software and install it onto the Macbook.

I can not figure out how to do this via a windows system.

Help!

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The process is explained over at [the Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or in more detail [on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/index.html) but probably the best method is using PenDriveLinux's [USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

From the installer, you can simply select your preferred version of Ubuntu, either download it automatically or browse for the ISO (if you've already downloaded it) and install it to a blank USB. You can then boot the MacBook from the USB on the MacBook, choose to install Ubuntu and you should be good to go!

Comment: Okay I installed it on my flash drive but when I turn on the MacBook I still have a white screen. I don't know if there is a specific command or something that is needed to initiate the installation maybe?

Also, for some reason I hadn't that of this before, would it be easier to take the blank harddrive out of the MacBook and plug it into my computer? That way I would be able to install it directly...?

I'm lost

Comment: You need to hold the Option key (fairly sure, but not a Mac user) to access the boot menu, and choose the USB. The second option you mention _might_ work, but no guarantees, as the hardware **is** quite different.

Comment: Okay I tried again except this time I held the Option Key. As a result, I was able to see the mouse cursor, but still had a white screen. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry @user238473 but you've hit the extent of my knowledge of Mac/OS X. Sorry :(